# Set XmlTextReader encoding to be "windows-1252"

Tags: c#, .net, xml, encoding

How to set XmlTextReader encoding to be "windows-1252" when I read a xml. I do not want to use the encoding from the xml.

```
XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(pathToXML);
```

NOTE: I have to use XmlTextReader instead of StreamReader in order to preserve line breaks.

Comment: Why not use XmlReader.Create?

Comment: @JohnSaunders the reason I use XmlTextReader is perserving multiple lines during reading. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283585/how-to-let-xdocument-load-preserve-line-break

Comment: Which line breaks? See the [XmlReaderSettings.IgnoreWhitespace Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.ignorewhitespace.aspx) to learn if that has the equivalent effect.

Comment: @JohnSaunders thanks, I will check that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(pathToXML, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252"), true);
XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(reader);
```

Should work