# Read XML file with UTF-8 Encoding

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to read an XML file which has some Lithuania characters in it. When I try to read it it shows some ????? instead. I'm using sqlbulcopy to import xml file to database.

How to read XML file in Encoding utf-8?

**Code Behind**

```
 string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/Data.xml"));

            DataTable dtHall = ds.Tables["Hall"];
            DataTable dtGroup = ds.Tables["HallGroup"];
            DataTable dtSeat = ds.Tables["HallSeat"];

            con.Open();

            using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
            {
                bc.DestinationTableName = "Hall";
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("HallID", "HallID");
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("TicketLimit", "TicketLimit");
                bc.WriteToServer(dtHall);
            }

            using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
            {
                bc.DestinationTableName = "HallGroup";
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("HallID", "HallID");
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("HallGroupID", "HallGroupID");
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("AZ", "AZ");
                bc.WriteToServer(dtGroup);
            }

            using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
            {
                bc.DestinationTableName = "HallSeat";
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("HallGroupID", "HallGroupID");
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("ShowSeatID", "ShowSeatID");
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("Color", "Color");
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("Price", "Price");
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("SeatRow", "SeatRow");
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("SeatNumber", "SeatNumber");
                bc.ColumnMappings.Add("IsReserved", "IsReserved");
                bc.WriteToServer(dtSeat);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to read file with utf-8 encoding, then pass to XmlReader. Answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284157/set-xmltextreader-encoding-to-be-windows-1252).

Comment: I Used StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("~/Data.xml", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252"), true);
XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(reader); But stil shows qustion marks.

Comment: Ok, first you need to find out encoding of file. Use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or similar app to find out the encoding. Then use this encoding to read file. Also, check if encoding is with [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: File is encoding in UTF-8 format.

Comment: Can you post your XML?

Comment: uploaded xml file here : http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=87570809238340174009

Comment: If the data is UTF-8, then use the `StreamReader` with `Encoding.UTF8` instead of Windows-1252 which is the windows default.

Comment: .NET uses Unicode by default and UTF8 for text files. Most likely the file is *not* stored as Unicode. BTW StreamReader uses UTF8 by default. 1252 on the other hand is an ASCII codepage

Comment: nothing changed. Maybe because i add xml import inside button click. All my added source code is inside button that send data to database.

Comment: @Paulius how did you check for the values? *Are* your database fields Unicode (nvarchar) or are you trying to store Unicode data to ASCII (varchar) fields? If you see `?` in the database, you probably tried to store Unicode in an ASCII field. If you see `?` in your strings, the file was *not* Unicode to begin with

Comment: @Paulus your sample file contains *only* ASCII Latin characters. This data would never cause conversion errors. Please post a sample file that *does* reproduce the error

Comment: Question marks is shown in database. I used nvarchar(50) data type for these values.

Comment: Actually his XML contains invalid chars. Check the line 5186, there is text like **Balkonas de�in�**. I opened the file using a hex editor. Hexadecimal representation of this line is `42 61 6C 6B 6F 6E 61 73 20 6B 61 69 72 EF BF BD`, last 3 bytes(__EF BF BD__) are not valid chars to display in [UTF8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) format.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OP's source data file contains human unreadable chars for UTF8 encoding. Even if OP configured his DB with correct param, still gonna see these chars.

Comment: @Paulius, I tried reading file using either UTF-8, Windows-1257, OEM 775, ISO 8859-13 and ISO 8859-4. Those chars are still visible in these encodings. Make sure that your source file is valid.

Comment: So where i need to put xml import?  when i delete ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/Data.xml")); files are stil importing to database.

Comment: @raidensan no, this is not an invalid character. � is the Unicode replacement character which means there was a conversion error when the file was *created* from a *non-Unicode* source using the wrong encoding

Comment: @Paulius your file *is* Unicode, it's read correctly. The problem is that it was created from a non-Unicode source using the wrong encoding. This has nothing to do with *reading* UTF8. Your export mechanism is broken, import works correctly'

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos +1 for correct explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file *is* Unicode - � is the Unicode replacement character. This would *not* appear if the file was ANSI.

When converting ANSI sources to Unicode using the wrong encoding, this character replaces any input characters that don't match the encoding.

For example, specifying Latin (Windows-1252), eg with `File.ReadAllText(somePath, .Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252"))` ,and trying to read Greek text (1253) will replace some Greek characters with �.

This means that there was a problem when *creating* the file. This can be caused by various reasons, all of which have to do with treating the data as ANSI at some point, using the wrong codepage:

- Perhaps the source was a file stored with a different single-byte encoding than the system's encoding, eg a file generated with 1253 was read on a machine whose system locale is 1252. The solution is either to use the proper encoding, or ensure the file is generated as UTF8 in the first place.
- The data may come from an ANSI database field (ie varchar) whose collation didn't match the content. The database driver would attempt to translate the data using the collation's codepage, resulting in an error. This is actually a database bug. The real solution is to replace the `varchar` field with an `nvarchar` field.

A possible workaround is to prevent character translation when loading from the database by adding the `Auto Translate=False` setting. Essentially, this reads and converts the ANSI data using the application's CultureInfo, not the field's collation.